# No email notifications received after creating a Task using Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, task-notifications

Task is created in Journey Builder via SFMC and pushed to salesforce as a task and expecting a mail to be sent to the Assigned User is what we're trying to achieve, and the email notification isn't happening.

Comment: is Email Deliverability off? Did you check?

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be with the CRM. Check you setting to ensure email notifications are turned on. Also, make sure the task assignee is different from who assigned the task. Here's a reference for what I mean: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335293&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1